# PHP: How to load a web page with a specific include?

Tags: php, html, include, file-handling

I'm working on a project where I have audio, video and picture files in different directories and want to write a simple web interface for those. I got everything working pretty good so far, pictures are displayed by lightbox, audio and video are played by jPlayer.

I have a directory stucture like this

```
ARCHIVE/
    _RES/
        CSS/
        JPLAYER/
        LIGHTBOX/
    index.php       #this is the start page with links to the other index.php files 

    VIDEO/

    PICTURES/
        ALBUM1/
            IMG/
            T_IMG/
            index.php
        ALBUM2/
            IMG
            T_IMG/
            index.php
        ALBUMn/
            IMG/
            T_IMG/
            index.php

    AUDIO
        ALBUM1
            index.php
            OGG/
                SONG#1.ogg
                SONG#n.ogg
                SONG FUN. ogg
            MP3/
                SONG#1.mp3
                SONG#n.mp3
                SONG FUN.mp3
```

My Problem now is, when I want to change something, for example, in the audio player, I have to edit every index.php in every ALBUMx/ directory inside AUDIO.

I'm sure there is a much simpler way: instead of have many index.php files, just having one index.php file, and when I click on link, AUDIO -> ALBUM1 it automatically loads a .html document that shows the audio player and fills the playlist with the audio files from the Album I choose.

This is example code for my AUDIO ALBUM index.php.

The ones for Pictures and Video look similar, except for having different player option e.g. for video or, in case of pictures, in has a lightbox implemented.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">


 <link href="/archive/_res/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<?php
    $parent = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
    $dirname = basename(__DIR__);
    echo '<title>'.$parent.$dirname.' </title>';
?>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- JPLAYER AUDIO VIDEO -->

<!--link type="text/css" href="../../_res/jplayer/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" /-->
<link type="text/css" href="../../_res/jplayer/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_res/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_res/jplayer/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>


<?php
$mp3folder = 'mp3/';
$oggfolder = 'ogg/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$mp3files = glob($mp3folder.'*.mp3');
$oggfiles = glob($oggfolder.'*.ogg');
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [';


for ($i=0; $i<count($mp3files); $i++) {
    $namerr[$i] = substr($oggfiles[$i],strlen($oggfolder),strpos($oggfiles[$i], '.')-strlen($oggfolder));
    echo '{'."\n";
    echo 'title:"'.$namerr[$i].'",'."\n";
    echo 'mp3:"'.dirname($mp3files[$i]).'/'.rawurlencode(basename($mp3files[$i])).'",'."\n";
    echo 'ogg:"'.dirname($oggfiles[$i]).'/'.rawurlencode(basename($oggfiles[$i])).'",'."\n";
    echo 'free: "true"'.','."\n";
    echo 'poster:"'.$mp3folder.'cover.png",'."\n";
    echo '},'."\n";
}
echo '
    ], {
        swfPath: "../../_res/jplayer",
        supplied: "ogg, mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        size: {
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-240p"
        },
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
});
</script>';

?>


<!-- JPLAYER AUDIO VIDEO //-->


<script>
            function bottop (div_id) {
              $('#'+div_id).animate({top:"-=140"},500, 'swing');
            }

            function topbot (div_id) {
              $('#'+div_id).animate({top:"+=140"},500, 'swing');
            }

            function fade_in (div_id) {
                      $('#'+div_id).fadeIn(0);
                }

            function fade_out (div_id) {
                      $('#'+div_id).fadeOut(0);
                }            

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="shownav" class="shnav">
    <span class="thinl4 db" onclick="topbot('topper');fade_out('shownav');">Show Navigation bar!</span>
</div>
<div id="topper">
    <div id="hidenav" class="shnav">
        <span class="thinl4 db" onclick="bottop('topper');fade_in('shownav');">Hide Navigation bar!</span>
    </div>

    <div id="backtoarchive" class="fl thinl">
        <table id="keks">
            <tr>
                <td class="bif"><</td>
                <td id="bli"><a href="#" class="blalis">Back to Archive</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <?php include '/var/www/webaccount/html/archive/_res/nav.php'; ?>

    <?php
        $parent = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
        $dirname = basename(__DIR__);
        echo '<div id="where" class="fl">';
        echo 'You are here: <em>'.$parent.$dirname.'</em>';
        echo '</div>';
    ?>

</div>

<div id="jplayer-wrap">
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-270p">
            <div class="jp-type-playlist">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div class="jp-gui">
                    <div class="jp-video-play">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-interface">
                        <div class="jp-progress">
                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                        <!-- added style below to fix floating issue (default was clear:both by css) -- not important to code function -->
                        <div class="jp-controls-holder" style="clear:left;">
                            <ul class="jp-controls">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="jp-toggles">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="shuffle">shuffle</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="shuffle off">shuffle off</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-title">
                            <ul>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered list -->
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <span>Update Required</span>
                    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I guess I would have to make single "modules" that contain the jplayer/lightbox stuff and `<?php include .. ?>` those and have it load the correct files. 
So when I click on a link for AUDIO -> ALBUM1 the html/php link should load something like 
`index.php?load=audio,files=audio/album1`

If someone has a hint for me, it would be so great!!!
This is my first PHP Project and I'm keen to learn!

Thank you,
vincent.

Comment: Or you could use a database and eliminate all of those .php files. The database keeps all the data in one place, and one **SINGLE** php scripts handles pulling up album information from the database and displaying it as necessary. The only files you should have on-disk are the actual music/art files.

Comment: Hey @MarcB – Thank you for your comment! Which data would sit in the database? Location of "art" files? How could I ensure that the index.php load the correct interface for audio/pic/video ?